# Selenium webdriver , Ruby, read children

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

I would like to read all the link children of this div:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 check-box-container">
    <a href="/applicant_submissions/5/background_checks/safis">
        <div id="safis" class="col-xs-2 check-box">
            <div class="check-styling pending">
                P
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="/applicant_submissions/5/background_checks/sori">
        <div id="sori" class="col-xs-2 check-box">
            <div class="check-styling passed">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="/applicant_submissions/5/background_checks/nsor">
        <div id="nsor" class="col-xs-2 check-box">
            <div class="check-styling pending-results">
                P
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>     
</div>
```

I would like to print out:

safis : P
sori :  ok
nsor : P

This is what I started  doing to see if I have an array that has 3 items, but it always return 0.

```
checkResults = driver.find_element(:class,'check-box-container').find_elements(:tag_name =>"a")
puts checkResults.size
```

Comment: I don't see a `ok` to construct `sori : ok`. Does this `ok` part of `glyphicon-ok`?

Comment: instead of displaying OK, they display the checked symbol of bootstrap.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get you. From where should I parse the `String` **ok**. How can I bring in `checked symbol of bootstrap` by Selenium? Am I missing something?

Comment: display just : sori : glyphicon-ok will be good.

Comment: Got it, Somehow would you like to consider an Answer in Java?

Comment: sure, let me see it in java, meanwhile if I can find a solution to this problem in ruby, thanks.

Comment: Did you try adding a wait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `id` and `Text Values` and print like `safis : P sori : ok nsor : P`, you can use the following equivalent code block (written in **`Java`**) :

```
List<WebElement> keyElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12 check-box-container']/a/div"));
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
for(WebElement key:keyElements)
    keys.add(key.getAttribute("id"));

List<WebElement> valueElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12 check-box-container']/a/div/div"));
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
for(WebElement value:valueElements)
    values.add(value.getAttribute("innerHTML"));

for(int i=0; i<keys.size();i++)
    System.out.println(keys.get(i) + " : " + values.get(i));
```

Comment: I have updated my work, I would like to check if the div contain a tagname that has a class attribute equal to "glyphicon glyphicon-ok" to puts the string "OK" instead of empty.

Comment: @Majid It is totally unethical to change the Question after you receive a satisfactory Answer as per stackoverflow standards. If my Answer have catered to your original Question in an agreed condition please Accept the Answer and feel free to raise a new Question as per your new requirement.

Comment: I am sorry, your code is in java, it's helping me but I am still working on it to work in ruby.

Comment: @Majid I think you have agreed to consider an Answer in `Java` and the update you committed within the question terming as `what I did` is completely my logic. That's pretty much unethical from your part. I repeat again, **If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new Question.**